# Choosing the right database for application that maintains hierarchy and reports

Tags: python, flask, web-applications, flask-sqlalchemy, gremlin

I wish to thank you you all for your answers. this has helped me understand how to build applications with Flask. However, I would wish to get your expert advice or opinion on an app I am using your course as a template to build.
I am building an app that will be used by an NGO, where everyone will be submitting reports. So everyone sends or saves their report for the week.
I have used a RDMS to build this but I think it falls short when implementing the structure

These reports should be seen by only those connected to an individual in the chain (like tree structure). Leader A can read reports of those down his chain. likewise, Leader 1A can read down his chain but Leader 2A cannot read into anyone not connected to his.

I was thinking of using two different types of databases.

1. a relational database for weekly reports
2. a graphical database for the structure.

reading on NOSQL, graphical database (gremlin), I see that the hierarchical structure I intend to will work. the graphical structure seems not to do well for submitting weekly reports that grows weekly and the number of people  will keep increasing. I am not sure of what to use in getting the most for efficiency and scalability.

Please I would love to hear or learn from your expert opinion on what way to go about modeling this such of structure to meet the needs of this app.